# What's the different between React Native and ReactXP

Tags: mobile, react-native

ReactXP is pretty new, nothing much about it out there.

AFAIK

1. Both ReactXP and React Native can build native mobile apps (iOS, Android).
2. ReactXP is something build on top of ReactJS/React Native.
3. Looks like the purpose of React Native and ReactXP are same -- building cross platform mobile apps.

Is it ReactXP just more Microsoft friendly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The authors of React use the phrase “learn once, write anywhere”.**

With React and React Native, your web app can share most its logic with your **iOS** and **Android** apps

**Problem:** the view layer needs to be implemented separately for each platform.

**ReactXP(Solution):** a thin cross-platform layer which can share your view definitions, styles and animations across multiple target platforms.

**More:** In general, it exposes APIs, components, props, styles and animation parameters that are implemented in a consistent way across React JS (HTML) and React Native for iOS and Android. A few platform-specific props and style attributes have been exposed, but we have tried to keep these to a minimum.

**Source/Reference:** https://microsoft.github.io/reactxp/

Answer (score 1):

`ReactXP` is built using `React` and `React Native`, and the lifecycle methods remain the same across both platforms. The main difference between `React Native` is that `ReactXP` works out of the box with not only `iOS` and `Android`, but also on the `web` and on `WindowsOS`!